# How to enable faster container rescheduling with Docker Swarm and Consul?

Tags: docker, consul, docker-swarm

**For some background on my environment:**

I have docker swarm running on 3 ubuntu 14.04 vagrant boxes.  The swarm master is running on 1 machine (with consul) and the other 2 machines are running swarm workers that are joined to the master. I set up the environment following the documentation page https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/.  It is working correctly so that any `docker -H :4000 <some_docker_command>` run from my master machine works fine. Service discovery is active as I am running the **gliderlabs/registrator** container on both of my workers.

**The issue:**

Any changes to my cluster, such as a node or container failure and the process of rescheduling containers (which are created with the tag `-e "reschedule:on-node-failure"`) by swarm occur within about 30 - 45 seconds.  By comparison when I was running fleet and etcd on CoreOS systems container rescheduling and notification of node failures occurred usually within about 5 seconds.  Is there any way to change some of the settings within consul and docker swarm to speed everything up to a level similar to what I experienced with fleet and etcd on CoreOS? If so what would I need to do?

**tldr:** I am running swarm with consul, container reschedualing and changes to the output of`docker -H :4000 ps` don't occur untill about 30 - 45 seconds after a node goes down.  How can I reduce this time period?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the TTL and [retries](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/reference/manage/#engine-failure-retry--set-engine-failure-retry-count) to lower values to get the swarm manager to act faster on failures.

For example:

```
docker run swarm manage --engine-failure-retry=1 consul:x.y.z.a:8500
```

Full [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/reference/manage/)